Can an xrdp server be configured to connect to an existing desktop session?
I'm running an xrdp server with its default Debian configuration. Once logged in, it maintains a virtual session to which I can reconnect. But it'd be much more convenient if I could connect to the existing :0 session (if it exists and belongs to the same user) so that I wouldn't need to kill and restart my browser and other apps in the virtual session. Is something like this possible?
